# How to unban a discord user given their ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

The code I'm currently using was perfectly fine, but I really want to unban with ID because it is much easier for me.

---

Current command is in a Cog file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class unban(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, *, member : discord.Member):
        banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
        member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

        for ban_entry in banned_users:
            user = ban_entry.user

            if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                await ctx.guild.unban(user)
                unban = discord.Embed(title='UnBan Hammer Has Spoken! :boom:', description=f'**Moderator:** {ctx.author}\n **User UnBanned:** {member}\n', color=0x10940b)
                unban.set_author(name="Moderating Action", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                await ctx.send(embed=unban)
                return

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(unban(client))
```

How can I update this code to unban using the user ID instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def unban(self, ctx, id: int) :
        user = await client.fetch_user(id)
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        await ctx.send(f'{user} has been unbanned')
```

this should work for you, you can personalize even more, but that's just the main code you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
async def unban(self, ctx, *, member : discord.User):
    await ctx.guild.unban(discord.Object(id = member.id))
    unban = discord.Embed(title='UnBan Hammer Has Spoken! :boom:', description=f'**Moderator:** {ctx.author}\n **User UnBanned:** {member}\n', color=0x10940b)
    unban.set_author(name="Moderating Action", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=unban)
```

Comment: How did it not work? Can you show me how you implemented this? I can help if you can show me that.

Comment: This won't work because your converter is trying to cast it to a `discord.Member`, which is impossible. When a person is banned, they are no longer part of that guild, so they can't be a `guild member`.